# How to get timestamp-neutral git hash from a given commit hash

Tags: git

While `git write-tree` seems to provide a time-neutral hash of the current state of the project *as staged*, I am not sure how to get a time-neutral hash for a given commit. Motivation: getting one would be useful for testing different commits for equality ― regardless of the commit time or the commit message.

Is there a way for obtaining such a hash for a given commit? a hash that does not factor the time or commit message of the commit but only the tracked files' contents?

Comment: admitteddly I am using an oldish git version: git version 1.9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substituting `CommitHash` for the given commit hash:

```
git rev-parse $CommitHash^{tree}
```

Comment: Not looking for changing how a commit is recorded, but how to get a hash of only the contents ― for a given commit

Comment: @matanster what you're describing is a tree hash.

Comment: how do I get one from a given commit then?

Comment: @matanster `git rev-parse somecommit^{tree}`

Comment: thanks. somehow this gives the same hash as the commit hash, for all commit hashes I try this on in my project.

Comment: @matanster that seems quite impossible to me — either the commit is malformed, or you're making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @matanster, perhaps you are on Windows? I think `^` is the escape character there. You might need to do something like `git rev-parse 'somecommit^{tree}'`.

Comment: for some silly reason I thought ^{tree} was an argument to be substituted. works now. many thanks.... feeling silly

Comment: I know im not supposed to do this, but +t @hobbs